# Creating object to get expected Json

Tags: java, jquery, json, gwt

I am working in GWT. Currently my requirement is simple. I want a JSON in following format:

```
{":question" : { ":id":"123", ":question_text":"some text", ":nodes":["123","111"]}}
```

I need to create an object in GWT code such that when I use jquery's json plugin to parse that object; I should get above listed json. This json needs to be sent to a remote service.

Currently I have tried using Java Hashmaps and Java custom objects modelled for these attributes but they always seem to have metadata in generated JSON and I am just not able to get this format.

It would be great if someone could suggest how I could go about modelling this data object such that I was get a JSON parsed as expected.

Or can I just write a simple custom JSON parser in Javascript? How do I do that?

cheers
-Priyank

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to do? Does your GWT application generate JSON? JSON is a protocol for serializing objects to strings and vice versa.

Comment: Yes very unclear indeed. If you just need JSON then write it in a string and pass that to javascript native code that calls jquery. GWT objects will always contain extra things since they are not just a plain mapping to a readable JSON string and all members and classes get obfuscated anyway.

Comment: yeah, I indeed just needed a json and finally I did pass it back in a native method. Initially I was just looking for how to ensure that I get exact JSON when given an object without meta-data being put into object. Maybe http://code.google.com/p/gwt-jsonizer/ this would have worked; but I never got down to trying it.

Comment: What is with the ":" before the keys? Why ":question" instead of "question"? I don't think that is going to work (at least on the javascript side)...

Comment: @cmccilloh - it works, but you may need to explicitly call (for example) `obj.get(":id")` rather than `obj.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to throw it out there, there are a few JSON Java libraries that are pretty nice and simple.  The two I have most of my experience with are:

- [JSON-Lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)
- [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

The benefit to both (and most other JSON libraries for Java) is that they handle marshalling most native Java object types to sane JSON equivalents -- in other words, they make it easy to add the contents of a variable to a JSON structure, whether the variable's an integer, long, string, boolean, whatever.  So with JSON-Lib, you could build your example as such:

```
int id = 123;
String questionText = "some text";
int[] nodes = new int[] { 123, 111 };

JSONObject question = new JSONObject();
question.put(":id", id);
question.put(":question text", questionText);
question.put(":nodes", nodes);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put(":question", question);

String jsonString = json.toString();
```